# Parse query gives nil outside himself

Tags: swift, parse-platform, null

Can someone explain me (or help) why im getting print like this:

```
A and B:[45.35924,14.39673,Name 1,0, 45.35509,14.40257,Name 2,7] // this is ok
C and D:nil //this is not
```

with this code:

```
var dataFromParse: Array<String>!

//im calling this func in viewDidLoad and I'm sending to it the ID for row in Parse
func getFromParse(ID: String) -> (){

    var take: AnyObject!
    var test: AnyObject!

    var query = PFQuery(className: "ClassName")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(ID){
        (getData: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error == nil){

            take = getData["stations1"]
            let json2 = JSON(take)
            self.dataFromParse = json2.arrayObject as Array<String>!

            test = json2.arrayObject as Array<String>!

        }
        else{
            println(error)
        }
        println("A:\(self.dataFromParse)")
        println("B:\(test)")
    }
    println("C:\(dataFromParse)") //i need print here like i'm printing it in println("A...
    println("D:\(test)")
}
```

This is problem because i need this **`dataFromParse`** in my whole program, not just in query.
I have tried with test variable inside func, but result is same.
So, how can I get this **`dataFromParse`** everywhere in program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this by calling this line of code everyvhere where I need data from Parse.com, and everything I need to do, Im doing inside if(!error) statement. It is not maybe officiant way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data when you receive it inside the completion handler so you can access it later. Where you have lines C and D, the data hasn't returned yet.

Comment: can you give me some example or direct me what to look at , because I tried to look for " how to save data from completion handler " but it is not quite clear to me how to apply this in my example.

Comment: You're already storing it in`dataFromParse`. Just don't access that until you've received all the info.

Comment: In my `viewDidLoad`, i'm first calling this function `getFromParse`, and then I'm tring to use `dataFromParse`, but it is still nil. Problem is that later in my code, I have some func for `UIPickerView` where I'm using data taken from Parse with that `getFromParse` function

Comment: Right, you need to update your UI after the data arrives. It won't be available in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I have found that this `getObjectInBackground` is asynchronously, so basicly it will be executed last. How can I update UI after it is executed, and can I make it run first somehow?

Comment: Make a method like `updateUI` that updates your UI elements. Call the method from the completion handler. You cannot make it run first.